# FParsec failing at the end of a spaces separated list, expecting another element of the list

Tags: parsing, f#, fparsec

I am trying to use FParsec to parse a list of zero or more elements of the form `[string]` where the string in the middle can be anything (except `]` as to disambiguate from the end of the string). Here is my code as is:

```
let parseArgumentList : Parser<string list, unit> =
    let parseArgument = (skipChar '[') >>. (manySatisfy (fun x -> x <> ']')) .>> (skipChar ']')
    sepBy (parseArgument) (spaces)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let parserResult = run parseArgumentList "[testString] [testString]"

    printfn "%A" parserResult
    0
```

The output here is:

```
Failure:
Error in Ln: 1 Col: 26
[testString] [testString]
                         ^
Note: The error occurred at the end of the input stream.
Expecting: '['
```

It is as if the parser is expecting another set of parenthesis rather than terminating at 2 occurances in `sepBy`. I tested this by changing the `spaces` to `(skipChar ' ') >>. spaces` and sure enough it parses fine. I am however unwilling to remove the option of no spaces between arguments. Any ideas or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using `sepEndBy` instead of `sepBy` will do what you want:

```ml
let parseArgumentList =
    sepEndBy parseArgument spaces
```

From the [FParser doc](https://www.quanttec.com/fparsec/reference/primitives.html#members.sepEndBy): The parser `sepEndBy p sep` parses zero or more occurrences of `p` separated and **optionally ended by** `sep`. (Emphasis added.)

Running this on your test input produces the expected result:

```
Success: ["testString"; "testString"]
```

Note that this solution also has the nice side-benefit of consuming trailing spaces, if there are any. E.g. When the input is `"[testString] [testString]    "`.